# How to get this embedded code to work in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

## Embedded code that works inside html

```
<div id="my-store-86556806"></div>
<div>
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?86556806&data_platform=code&data_date=2023-04-11" charset="utf-8"></script><script type="text/javascript"> xProductBrowser("categoriesPerRow=3","views=grid(20,3) list(60) table(60)","categoryView=grid","searchView=list","id=my-store-86556806");</script>
</div>
```

How do i get it to work in a reactjs component?

## I tried using custom hooks

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
const importScript = resourceUrl=> {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = resourceUrl;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, [resourceUrl]);
};
export default importScript;
```

```
import importScript from 'customHooks/importScript';
const Demo = props => {
  importScript("/path/to/resource.js");
}
```